# Что за тестовые проверки отключены в бете?

Tags: обсуждение

> Тестовые проверки в стадии беты отключены. Никакой валидации ваших действий при разборе очереди не проводится. Поэтому иногда стоит возвращаться назад при провеке очереди и оценивать, насколько ваше решение совпало с решением остальных проверяющих. Если вы отметили "выглядит нормально" то, что 6 других пользователей решили рекомендовать к удалению - значит вы скорее всего нажали не ту кнопку.

Собственно вопрос, а что это за тестовые проверки?

Comment: Сегодня прошел первую (для себя) такую проверку. Удивился. Мы вроде не вышли из беты и в ней эта штука вроде не работает

Comment: @tutankhamun, уже давно включили, я раз 10 натыкался - большую часть прошёл :) Вот только что ещё одну прошёл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На английском SO в очереди проверки иногда появляются вопросы, которые уже были проверены раньше, и по которым уже было принято решение (участниками и модератором) - удалить или оставить.

Если ваше решение не совпадет с уже принятым - показывается предупреждение. После нескольких неправильных решений доступ к очереди ограничивается. На неделю или дольше.

Подробности расписаны на английской мете: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Николас обещал что их включат в скором времени - судя по всему, они были выключены по ошибке.

Проголосовать "все ок" на ответе-ссылке - верный способ завалить проверку.

Comment: И 128 голосов за комментарий "I'd like a "I still disagree, your test if flawed" button for "failed" tests." :)

Comment: *Если ваше решение не совпадет с уже принятым - показывается предупреждение* — «вы можете иметь любое мнение, но при условии, что оно совпадает с мнением окружающих».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мнение и решение - разные понятия :)